# Import JS function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, import, export

I have a JS file that exports some functions. I need one of those in the download attribute of the HTML body tag. How do I import the JavaScript function into the inline HTML?

I tried the following:

*JS file*

```
export function initPage() { ... }
```

*HTML file*

```html
<script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```html
<body onload="initPage()">
```

But I get this error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initPage is not defined
```

(This may be a duplicate Stack Overflow question, but I cannot find it again).

Comment: Where/how are they `imported`?

Comment: That's my question. I want to import it directly into the HTML Tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution which is very easy, not quite exact that what I wanted but it works:

```
<script type="module">
    import {initPage} from "./js/file.js";
    document.querySelector("body").onload = function () { initPage(); } ;
</script>
```

Now the `<script>`-Tags with a src attribute aren't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could try following:

```html
{...}
<body>
{...}

<!-- End of the body -->
<script type="module">
import {initPage} from '...';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  initPage();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Basically the event listener DOMContentLoaded might be a modern way of solving your problem.

Comment: This would go to the end of the JS file, right?

Comment: No, at the end of the html document. I'll adjust the example.

Comment: Oh, OK, sorry, I was stupid.

Comment: It's all about experience, I wouldn't call it "stupid" :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some tries and what seemed to work for me was to remove type="module" from the script tag and the export from the js function

Edit: What I meant was something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initPage()">
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
function initPage() {
  console.log('hupp');
}
```

Comment: No, I want to use the module syntax. If I removed that, I would get an error like "Imports may only appear on the top level of the module" or so.